# How to automate adding explicit types to a large codebase?

Tags: swift, xcode

What I'd like to do is automate updating code in an Xcode project that does not declare a type to code that does declare a type:

Input:

```
let str = "This is a string"
```

Output:

```
let str: String = "This is a string"
```

Comment: Actually it **does** declare a type. You should not annotate types the compiler can infer.

Comment: This is a classical X-Y problem. You are trying to solve a problem that is not even a problem but a benefit. Instead simplify your codebase, fix your architecture and use independent modules.

Comment: @vadian Why shouldn't you annotate these types?

Comment: @aryanm Swift is a very clean language and it's recommended to omit all redundant Information. It's pretty clear that a string literal is a `String`.

Comment: Apple recommends providing the compiler with explicit type information to improve build efficiency for complex values: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/improving-build-efficiency-with-good-coding-practices

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a tool that does that already, however, looks like it's a weekend project that includes SwiftSyntax https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax and SourceKit https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten together. SwiftSyntax can read and output "fixed" code, while SourceKit can provide a type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the swiftlint rule `explicit_type_interface` to enforce it to a certain degree: https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/explicit_type_interface.html.

But there doesn't seem to be a way to enforce this without swiftlint.

However, implicit typing is a *benefit* of swift, not a detriment, so I would advise caution if you're thinking of enforcing explicit typing just for compilation improvements. There are better ways to improve compile times.

Comment: Ah I missed the "automated" part. Thanks.

Comment: On big project it's a clearly not an improvement, would you mind sharing the better ways and why this approach would not contribute to speed things up ?

Comment: @h.martin When your project compile slowly, it's usually a problem with architecture. Swift has modules - split your application into independent modules and your compile time will be reduced by several degrees. This is really simple now when we have Swift packages. You can just put a part of your codebase into a folder, create a package definition and your module is ready.
Explicit types are a readability disaster, especially when dealing with generics, closure parameters etc. No longer you can just write `.filter { $0.isValid }`, you have to write `.filter { MyType -> Bool in $0.isValid }`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually find ways to use find and replace, for instance search for space
= space " and then replace with : String = " That's the best way I have found.